# Error while saving multiple data frames using write.xls()

Tags: python, r, xls

Having made sure that the library is installed and Python 2.7.7 is in the PATH...

```
> library(dataframes2xls)
> shell("PATH")
PATH=D:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64;D:\Python27\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\java\bin\client\
```

...I'm getting this weirdness while trying to save 2 dataframes:

```
> write.xls(c(mtcars, iris), file = "myframes.xls")
D:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'D:/Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Warning message:
running command 'python D:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/library/dataframes2xls/python/csv2xls.py -i C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeinq3z/csvfile1.csv,C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeinq3z/csvfile2.csv -o myframes.xls -s Sheet1,Sheet2 ' had status 2
```

What does this mean and how to solve it?

**EDIT:** Just as @machow pointed out, the problem was the space in the folder's name. Installing R into a different folder without a space in its name solved the problem. However, is there another, more sensible solution?

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the whitespace in `D:/Program Files`. So, when it runs `python D:/Program Files/R/...`, the interpreter takes `D:Program` as the first argument.

Comment: Just as an alternative way to save multiple data.frames to Excel file - http://statmethods.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/quickly-export-multiple-r-objects-to-an-excel-workbook/

Comment: @machow sounds plausible. What would you recommend to remedy this situation? Do you think installing R to some other folder without space in its name would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of write.xls, lines 160-162 look as though it's just pasting arguments and feeding them to `system()`:

```
csv2xls.cmd = paste(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9,arg10,arg11,arg12,sep="")
if (system.returnvalue == 0) {
    system.returnvalue = system(csv2xls.cmd)
```

However, it doesn't put strings around directories or escape spaces. [The link](http://statmethods.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/quickly-export-multiple-r-objects-to-an-excel-workbook/) given by @DrDom seems like a good alternative. After installing the `xlsx` package and sourcing the `save.xlsx` function from the link, you would just do

```
save.xlsx('myframe.xlsx', mtcars, iris)
```

Comment: Thanks to you both, guys. @DrDom's solution seems indeed nice, but it's giving me some fresh new kind of java weirdness, so I'm glad we have found a solution to the original question (which seems to be, either install R somewhere else or change the source of the function). Accepted/upvoted.